# Show ads after every 5 items on grid view in flutter

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, flutter-test

I want to show an ad after every 5 items in flutter grid view,
so I want to make something like this,

[image]

keep in mind that the products and the ads will be in separate lists that are  dynamically populated from json
Also When the user click the Ad i want it to have Different Action, not the same as that of the product

my grid view code look something like this:

```
List<Product> _products = [];     ///product list populated from json
List<Ads> _ads = [];              ///ads i want to show populated from json

   StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      shrinkWrap:true,
      itemCount: _products == null ? 0 : _products.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
        Container(),
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.fit(2),
      mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
    );
```

Thanks alot,

**Edit:**
what if I want to show the ads in my _ads list one by one according to their index in the builder, how will that turn out
example of what I am trying to do:

```
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
  ),
  itemCount: 30,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Center(
        child: ((index + 1) % 6 == 0) ? Text( _ads[index].title) : Container(child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            memCacheHeight: 500,
                            imageUrl: CallApi().assetUrl() +
                                _products[index].image),),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
 GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
      ),
      itemCount: 30,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Center(
            child: ((index + 1) % 6 == 0) ? Text('AD') : Container( ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Result Screen->  [image: imGe]

Comment: thanks alot @Ravindra S. Patil .. what if I want to show the ads in the list one by one according to their  index in the builder, how can I do that

Comment: I can't understand can you explain me in detail

Answer (score 1):

Make the length of the grid adv + products length and then add this logic :
It will show adv at every 5th position eg 5,10,15... etc

```
List<Product> _products = [];     ///product list populated from json
List<Ads> _ads = [];              ///ads i want to show populated from json

   StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      shrinkWrap:true,
      itemCount: _products == null ? 0 : _products.length + _ads.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => 
    if( (index + 1) % 6 == 0 ) showAdv() 
    else Container(),
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.fit(2),
      mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
    );
```